# In line.split('+')[-1] what does the -1 in the square brackets indicate in Python

Tags: python, syntax

Let's assume that we have this code:

```
name = line.split('+')[-1]
```

What does the -1 do? I have seen it in various codes but not sure on what it does?
And what would the difference be if there was a `[0]` or a `[1]`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The line of code you gave is basically doing three things:

1. It takes the string `line` and splits it on `+`'s using [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).  This will return a list of substrings:

   ```
   >>> line = 'a+b+c+d'
   >>> line.split('+')
   ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
   >>>
   ```
2. The `[-1]` then indexes that list at position `-1`. Doing so will return the last item:

   ```
   >>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'][-1]
   'd'
   >>>
   ```
3. It takes this item and assigns it as a value for the variable `name`.

Below is a more complete demonstration of the concepts mentioned above:

```
>>> line = 'a+b+c+d'
>>> line.split('+')
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> lst = line.split('+')
>>> lst[-1]
'd'
>>> lst[0]
'a'
>>> lst[1]
'b'
>>> lst[2]
'c'
>>> lst[3]
'd'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Negative indexes in Python are syntactic sugar for accessing the elements in reverse order, from right-to-left, starting in `-1`. So `-1` is the last item, `-2` is the second-to-last item, and so on - the first item would be `lst[-len(lst)]`. For example:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
lst[-1]
=> 3
lst[-2]
=> 2
lst[-3]
=> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

[`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) returns a list:

```
>>> '1+2+3'.split('+')
['1', '2', '3']
```

`list[-1]` yields the last item (negative index starts from -1)

```
>>> '1+2+3'.split('+')[-1]
'3'
>>> '1+2+3'.split('+')[0] # the first item (Python index starts from 0)
'1'
>>> '1+2+3'.split('+')[1]
'2'
```

See [`Lists` - Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) (contains indexing, slicing).

Answer (score 0):

`Split` will create list and from that you are getting the last element using `[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in order to understand what is happening here, we need to understand lists, split() and slicing functions of a list.

For example:

   Given the string below, let us split it:
•   line ='a+b+c+d'
•   name=line.split(‘+’)

   After splitting the string, it becomes a list. As shown below
•   ['a','b','c','d']

   Please note: '+' is called the separator : meaning, the string will be separated based on the number of '+' available, hence the list above.

   Square brackets after the separator(always in normal parenthesis) is accessing the elements in the list
 Lists are accessed using index, positive index begins with 0 (which is the first element of a list.e.g name[0] is accessing first element of the list which is ‘a’) and it operates from left to right while negative indexes starts from -1, from right to left(in the example above 'd' is index -1)
Using your sample question, 
name = line.split('+')[-1] , this will return last item in the list, that is ‘d’
name = line.split('+')[0], this will return first item in the list, that is ‘a’
name = line.split('+')[1], this will return second  item in the list, that is ‘b’